# Regex a json object inside of string

Tags: json, regex, string

I'm currently working on parsing out json objects from a string(and I'm close), but my regex just can't handle multiple objects throughout the string.

Here's my current regex:

```
/(\[{|\{)(?=.)(?: [^*] | (R) )*(\}]|\})/g
```

And here is my test string. I'm trying to capture both type of objects, `{...}` and `[{...}]`.

Below is the string test string that I'm using.

> Here is some json string for regex to parse [{"funarray": [12, 343,
>   4], "name": "John Doe", "age": 23, "_id":
>   "ad14ab20-df9a-11e7-9ece-3b010fca83e0", "created_at": 1513124107987 },
>   {"name": "Jane Doe", "age": 28, "_id":
>   "ad167fe0-df9a-11e7-9ece-3b010fca83e0", "created_at": 1513124107998 },
>   {"name": "John Smith", "age": 21, "_id":
>   "ad16a6f0-df9a-11e7-9ece-3b010fca83e0", "created_at": 1513124107999 }]
>   And heres the end of the string! But if we add another json object at
>   the end, it shouldn't capture this middle string. {"funarray": [12,
>   343, 4], "name": "Greg Johnson", "age": 20, "_id":
>   "da54a650-df9a-11217-9ece-3faebe8320", "created_at": 1513124186254
>   }.This string here shouldnt be captured either.

Comment: See [Safely turning a JSON string into an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015/safely-turning-a-json-string-into-an-object).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Unfortunately that wouldn't work in my case since these strings that I'll be parsing will be logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out after realizing my initial question was actually invalid regex for javascript. Here is the answer:

`(\[{|\{)(?=.)(?:[^.+]|(R))*(\}]|\})(?=.)`